# Calculate double discount with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to calculate double discount using jquery, now i use this for calculate one discount

code :

```
var disc = 5;
var price = 10000;
var total_1 = Math.round(price*disc/100);
var total_2= price - total_1;
```

but how if the disc is: `var disc = 5+10;`

thankyou

Comment: You can total all the disc in one variable with sum, and then you can do it as it is.

Comment: it's unclear what you want, write a formula for your calculations

Comment: @Loading.. no, if i total all the disc the result give not correct value

Comment: This is plain JavaScript. It has nothing to do with jQuery. BTW, what do you mean by "double discount"? Is the final price equal to `originalPrice*(1 - (5+10)/100)`? Or is the final price equal to `originalPrice*(1 - 5/100)*(1 - 10/100)`?

Comment: @Maximus i don't know how to calculate this to array and loop automaticly the rule in my php is the var disc is explode an be array so i use foreach to loop and calculate..

Comment: @shaochuancs can you convert this to javascript i'm new in javascript so i don't know how to implement this to javascript $disc = array('5','10');->from 5+10 foreach($disc as $val){
   $total= $total- ($price*($val / 100)); 
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use javascript array to store the discounts one-by-one.
eg.

```
var dis=[5,10];
var price = 10000, total_1, total_2;
total_2=price;
for(var i=0; i < dis.length; i++){
   total_1 = Math.round(total_2 * dis[i]/100);
   total_2= total_2 - total_1;
}
```

You will get answer in `total_2`

Answer (score 1):

Create a discount calculating function and pass discount value to it as parameter

```
function CalculateDiscount(disc,price)
{
var total_1 = Math.round(price*disc/100);
return price - total_1;
}
```

And call this whenever you want discouted value

```
var discountedPrice1 = CalculateDiscount(5, 10000);
var discountedPrice2 = CalculateDiscount(10, discountedPrice1);
```